# Почему когда запускаю сайт с пк, то он выглядит как нужно, но когда заливаю на хостинг, то он ломается?

Tags: веб-программирование, браузер, хостинг, кроссбраузерность

Использую один и тот же браузер. Когда запускаю с пк, сайт выглядит нормально , но когда заливаю на хостинг он ломается . Думал , что просто залил не те файлы , но проверил раз 10 и проблема точно не в этом.

Обновление: проверил сайт через Opera и Microsoft Edge , проблемы возникаю только с Хромом

http://sketch.zzz.com.ua/

Ошибка: *Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.*

Обновление: Запустил сайт с другого пк через хром - отображается нормально . Проблема почему-то только у меня на комп'ютере.

Обновление : Проблема решилась сама собой притом , я даже малейшего понятия не имею как.

Comment: А что показывает? Какой код ошибки, например? Как по мне, так не понятно же ничего...

Comment: @mrEvgenX Добавил ссылку на сайт . Никакой ошибки нет , возможно просто два браузера читают код по-разному .Просто раньше проблем с хромом не было.

Comment: Открывайте инструменты разработчика, смотрите ошибки в консоли...

Comment: Можно еще кеш браузера очистить, мало ли там что-то завалялось.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю,тему можно закрыть .
В таких случиях попробуйте зайти с другого пк на ваш сайт через нужный вам браузер. Возможно , проблема с софтом у вас , а не с кодом вашего сайта